# Wordpress theme configuration page doesn't load

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, wordpress-theming

i've deployed wordpress on my app-engine, i've added a theme-forest theme on my local version and activated it.
This theme has its own configuration section on the Admin view and it works only on the local version of the site. When deployed it doesn't load.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJEwI.jpg (this is the problem)

Do you have any idea of what's wrong? Maybe the appl.yaml file (i've used the standard one).

Thank you,
Leandro

```
application: my-app-id
    version: wpfromstarterproject
    runtime: php
    api_version: 1`

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|svg|pdf))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|svg|pdf|)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|svg))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|svg)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?\.zip$
- ^(.*/)?\.bat$
- ^(.*/)?\.sh$
- ^(.*/)?\.md$`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That must be a problem with the serialized data or with the transients.

Try to migrate the database with : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

And also delete all your transients on the database...
To do this you must execute the next line :

> DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('%_transient_%');

Also you try to read the error's log file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the log (i'm new on app-engine and i didn't know where to look).

I've found this: 
`16:27:46.933 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /base/data/home/apps/s~fast-sign-687/wpfromstarterproject.379053694305580795/wordpress/wp-content/themes/reload/includes/framework/inc/fields/typography/field_typography.php on line 221`

So i have to activate curl extension. Do you know if it's possible just by editing the root php.ini in the project?

Comment: Well it seems that you will need to edit field_ty‌​pography.php and use [urlfetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/), [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).
Edit: I found [purl](https://github.com/azayarni/purl) that seems get the job done without effort.

Comment: Yeah you're right! I've edited it  as you suggest and it works. I will post the solution as soon as I will feel better from the flu. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this starter project: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project

That project contains this app.yaml:

```
application: your-project-id
version: wpfromstarterproject
runtime: php
api_version: 1
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$
static_files: wordpress/\1
upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$
application_readable: true
- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$
application_readable: true
- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
static_files: wordpress/\1
upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$
application_readable: true
- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
secure: always
- url: /wp-admin/
script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
secure: always
- url: /wp-login.php
script: wordpress/wp-login.php
secure: always
- url: /wp-cron.php
script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
login: admin
- url: /xmlrpc.php
script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php
- url: /wp-(.+).php
script: wordpress/wp-\1.php
- url: /(.+)?/?
script: wordpress/index.php
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?\.zip$
- ^(.*/)?\.bat$
- ^(.*/)?\.sh$
- ^(.*/)?\.md$
```

It worked fine for me ! I can provide you with more details if you had some issues in testing that.

I hope this helps,

Zouhaier

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I've edited my post with the appl.yaml used.
But it isn't a solution,, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please share with me more details of the issue, may be i'll better understand where it's blocking and help?

Comment: Ok, i've found that the problem is that the theme is using curl

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /base/data/home/apps/s~id/wpfromstarterproject.379053694305580795/wordpress/wp-content/themes/reload/includes/framework/inc/fields/typography/field_typography.php on line 221`

But it seems that curl is not supported by the app-engine. I thought that was enough to edit the roo pho.ini file but i didn't find any confirmation. Have you some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, at work again.

The solution was to change the use of cURL with file_get_contents

`$url = ReduxFramework::$_url . 'inc/fields/typography/googlefonts.html';`

```
// New Code
$data = [''];
$data = http_build_query($data);
$context = ['http' => ['method' => 'get']];
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$googleHTML = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
// Old Code
/*$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$googleHTML = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);*/
// Just a check used in the template
if (empty($googleHTML)) {
    $googleHTML = false;
}
```

So the "Old Code" is the one not supported by appengine and you have to replace it with the "New Code" section.

Hope it helps.
Thank you everyone for the support.

Leandro